# angular-ui-router Multiple Views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to use angular-ui-router, I has a index.html and javascript like this:

```js
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp',['ui.router']);

mainApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$httpProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.when('','/index');
  $stateProvider.state('index',{
    url:"/index",
    views:{
      'menu':{
        templateUrl:'views/menu.html'
      },
      'content':{
        templateUrl:'views/content1.html'
      }
    }
  }).state('index.content1',{
    url:"index/content1",
    views: {
      'content@index': {
        templateUrl: 'views/content1.html'
      }}
  }) .state('index.content2',{
    url: 'index/content2',
    views: {
      'content': {
        templateUrl: 'views/content2.html'
      }
    }
  })
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="mainApp">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 column text-center bg-primary">
            Title
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 column bg-danger">
          <div ui-view="menu"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 column bg-info">
         <div ui-view="content">

         </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

menu.html

```html
<ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="index.content1"  ui-sref-active="active">menu1</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="index.content2"  ui-sref-active="active">menu2</a></li>
</ul>
```

But when I chlick "menu1" or "menu2" link in then menu.html, "content1" or "content2" not be load, Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change child states URL to be mentioning on child route part. Ui-router engine will take care of URL formation based on states hierarchy.

And then make your make your `content` named view as `relative` by adding `@` after your named view, since you wanted to changed named view which is the part of `index`(parent) state.

```
.state('index.content1', {
  url: "/content1",
  views: {
    'content@': {
      templateUrl: 'views/content1.html'
    }
  }
}).state('index.content2', {
  url: '/content2',
  views: {
    'content@': {
      templateUrl: 'views/content2.html'
    }
  }
})
```

[**Plunker Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zYLeVYPBpWfSI1ORVKX7?p=preview)

Comment: i changed,but it still not work, are there any o other mistakes?

Comment: @felix1982 checkout my edit.. I had also included demo plunker as well.